# Swift / How to get the current adress of Map pin

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, maps

I want to make `google map` integration, I already have a `GMSMapView` and it's working fine.

But what I want to do exactly is that when I slide the Map and move to another part of the world get the address of the earth pin where is located fixed pin

Unfortunately I can not find a solution anywhere. I can not place afixed pin in the center of screen.

So I want to place the fixed pin and when the user try to move the map get  changed value of address depend on that pin where is located in the map

Comment: are you using GMSMapView this class ?

Comment: Yes I am using GMSMapView

Answer (score 1):

try this, implement the method `func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, idleAtCameraPosition position: GMSCameraPosition)` of `GMSMapViewDelegate` so when mapView stop of moving you get the address of the camera position

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, idleAtCameraPosition position: GMSCameraPosition) {

    let centerCoordinates = position.target;

    GMSGeocoder().reverseGeocodeCoordinate(centerCoordinates) { (response:GMSReverseGeocodeResponse?, error:NSError?) in
        if(error != nil)
        {
            return
        }
        var address = response?.firstResult()?.lines?.joinWithSeparator(",")
        address = address?.stringByAppendingFormat(", %@", (response?.firstResult()?.country)!)
    }

}
```

I hope  this helps you, for me works